# navbar overlay not staying together in one row when minimizing screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with my nav bar! I want my nav bar to keep its size when page gets minimized. The navbar pieces go below eachother when I reduce the width of my browser window.

**Before** reduction of width of browser window
[image: before minimize navbar]

**After** reduction of width of browser window
[image: After minimize navbar]

**The navbar code:**

```html
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="">

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right", style="">


   <li class="dropdown" style="">

                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Students<span class="caret"></span>
                     </a>

                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li><%= link_to "Life", "/boards/1" %></li>
                       <li><%= link_to "Admissions", "/boards/2" %></li>
                       <li><%= link_to "Advice", "/boards/3" %></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Business<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">           
                      <li><%= link_to "Culture", "/boards/4" %></li>
                      <li><%= link_to "Invest", "/boards/5" %></li>
                      <li><%= link_to "Advice", "/boards/6" %></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

<% if(!user_signed_in?) %>
       <li> <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %> </li>
       <li> <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %> </li>
       <% else %>

       <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%= current_user.username %> <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "My Profile", user_path(current_user) %></li>
           <li><a href="/your_essays">My Essays</a></li>
          <li><a href="/your_reservations">Requests</a></li>
          
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>

        <li class="thumbnail2"><%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb), :id => "image-tag", class: "portrait") %></li>
      </li>
      <% end %>
      <!--  this is where it's different-->

            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li>
                <a href="/conversations"><span class="label label-danger"><%=unread_messages_count%></span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Messages</a>
              </li>
             <!--  <li>
                <%= link_to 'Messages', conversations_path %>
              </li> -->
              <li>
                
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/revisers"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Become a Reviser</a>
              </li>
            <% else %>
            <% end %>
           
    </ul>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
</script>
    <div class="navbar-header" style="">
      <%= link_to "EssayFriends", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    </div>

<div style="width:360px;max-width:360px;margin-left:200px;top: 50%;transform: translateY(12%);">
   <%= render 'users/school_search' %>  
</div>
  

   </div>
  
</div><!--/.container-fluid -->

</nav>
```

```css
.textbox-search {
  height:40px;
  width: 20rem;
  font-size: 18px;
  
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}


.container {
    width: 95%;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}




.alert {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #45d1b8;
    border-color: #45d1b8;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-links {
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family:Helvetica;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why my nav bar is doing this and the fix??? Thank you!!! I want the nav bar to shrink and not show unless you scroll over like stackoverflow navbar!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your in need of some [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

1: Find the breakpoint that the navbar breaks at.

2: Make the media query

```
@media(max-width: 89.5em) /*1432px   1em =~ 16px */
{
     #your-css-selector
     {
          /*Your code here*/
     }

}
```

You've got a lot of stuff in that bar, if you want to keep the size, you'll likely need to make the text smaller, and possibly hide an element like the search bar.

Or you could always consider creating a [collapsable nav](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp). But ultimately whatever you choose to do will be more of a design choice than anything.

Comment: What is the css-selector in my code?? Im not sure what that means? is it nav?? just a hint or something of the code? is it css code?

Answer (score 0):

It is breaking because there is not space. You have to use something like hamburger menu to retain the height. Check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)